# What should be the maximum length of the field considering it also have sub-fields/components?

Tags: hl7

If a field (for example in the `PID` segment) in an HL7 message contains sub-fields/components (e.g. the field `PID.11.1` with `&` character delimiter) how I can calculate the length of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum length of *field* is total number of characters in all sub-fields/components.

Let us continue with your example [`PID.11.1`](http://hl7-definition.caristix.com:9010/HL7%20v2.3.1/segment/PID). The maximum length of the field is 106 with datatype [`XAD`](http://hl7-definition.caristix.com:9010/HL7%20v2.3.1/segment/PID?version=HL7%20v2.3.1&dataType=XAD) (Extended Address). This datatype may have multiple sub-fields/components. Note that *Length* column in there is displayed zero.

[image: XAD Datatype]

So the maximum length of 106 can be consumed by only one component, or it can be split by two or more components.

**Just a suggestion:** Apart from standards, one must also take in to account the other party that is supposed to consume the message. There might be additional length related validations though does not match with specifications.